# Spring Boot : Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.JoinTable

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

## Problem Statement

I am receiving the following exception when I run my Spring Boot application.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindJoinedTableAssociation(AnnotationBinder.java:2548)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

The method's class, javax.persistence.JoinTable, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Usuario/IdeaProjects/spring-security/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/JoinTable.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/Usuario/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/JoinTable.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.persistence.JoinTable: file:/C:/Users/Usuario/IdeaProjects/spring-security/lib/javax.persistence.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.JoinTable


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is the contents of my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security</name>
    <description>spring-security</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How to I remove one of the versions of `javax.persistence.JoinTable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Multiple javax.persistence.JoinTable

The issue is most likely related to the duplicate javax.persistence.* libraries.  I see you have the following two dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Remove the `org.springframework.data.spring-data-jpa` dependency.**

The `org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency already includes `org.springframework.data.spring-data-jpa` which is being added transitively.

Make sure to run a `mvn clean` before packaging and testing the new jar file

## Non Maven lib directory

It also looks like there is a lib directory in your project that may have dependencies that are not managed by Maven.  Please delete at least the `javax.persistence` library from that location